# LibreOffice Calc: Wrapping text while not expanding the cell's height in just 1 row

Tags: libreoffice

I have a large document in Libre Calc. All the rows and columns have "wrap text" option selected and all the cells' height is automatically adjusted to the text... BUT I found one row which, even though has the text wrapped, doesn't expand the height of the cell. The height stays at the height of one-line of the text, no matter how much text I will write there and how many lines of wrapped text it will create inside the cell. It just shows me that small red arrow. I checked the properties and they seem to be exactly the same as the properties of all the rest of the rows. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you try the answer you got [here?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/72044/wrapping-text-while-not-expanding-the-cells-height-in-just-1-row/) What were your results?

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting (Jan 2017 with v5.0.3.2) showed this works: Select the column you want to wrap then click Format Row, choose Optimum Height and untick the Default Value box. Not intuitive but the cells magically wrapped themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Select row, do right mouse button click, choose "Size", than "Row height", and check "Fit to size" check-box.

The right mouse button menu:

[image]

The "Fit to size" checkbox:

[image]